# When can we link to pictures direct, ie. posting [img]http://ubuntuone.com/mypic7YREE555.jpg[/img]?

Tags: discussion

Would be nice to be able to post images directly rather than a coded web page.
i.e. so we can use pictures in forums, emails, http image etc.
Any idea if this will be implemented?

Comment: The is best discussed on Meta - not here.  When you have enough rep you will be able to post pictures directly into your question or answer.

Answer (score 5):

On Ask Ubuntu, you need to use the proper [markdown](http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help) for this:

`![image description](http://ubuntuone.com/mypic7YREE555.jpg)`

Results in the image being embedded.

Comment: Also: `<img src="http://example.com/test.gif">` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Although the link Ubuntu One provides doesn't end with `.jpg` you can still use it on the Ubuntu forums as you have described:

```
[img]http://ubuntuone.com/1bwxP9xWhvm3mvB2t2zkMn[/img]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) to be able to insert a picture in your post: that [privilege](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) comes at [10 reputation points](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user). A single upvote on an answer, or two on a question, will bring you to this point; the restriction is solely there to prevent drive-by spammers from posting images.

To insert an image in your post, click the `img` button in the editor toolbar or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then enter a link to the picture on the Web or the location of the picture file on your computer. The image will be uploaded to Stack Exchange's servers, so that it's always available.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, thats possible.  I tryd it with a html file and Google Chrome.